# Execute C++ exe from C# form using Process.start()

Tags: c#, process.start

I'm trying to create a C# form app that will allow me to use all of my previous C++ programs from one central program.

I'm able to open the exes with `Process.Start()`, however it does not compile the code correctly.

Example code:

```
Process.Start("C:\\\Documents and Settings\\\dan\\\Desktop\\\test.exe");
```

This will bring up the console and act like it's running, but it does not run like when I normally compile out of the C++ editor. Is there a `startinfo` variable I need to set to signify that it's a C++ program or something along that line?

Also, is there any way to execute a C++ program using `process.start` that will allow me to pass it variables through the command line via `argc` and `argv`?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean mean you say it doesn't run the same? What is different?

Comment: @Dan: Why should your C++ test.exe know or care that it's written in C++ vs. any other language?  What's the precise difference between what you see and what you expect?

Comment: It doesn't fully run, it just brings up the console, prints out the first couple prompt lines and halts, does not run all the way through to create the output. I tried this with several different C++ exes all giving the same result.

Comment: Is this behavior because you are not passing in any arguments?

Comment: I got it to work, my issue was the working directory and shell execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only a couple of differences when you use Process.Start the way you did vs. when you just execute the program directly.  Both can be addressed by using [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).

1. The [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) will not be the same.  Set this to the path containing the executable to get the same behavior.
2. Set [UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) to true, so the windows shell is used to execute the process.

As for adding command line arguments: You can do that via [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx).  There shouldn't be one required due to it being a C++ application, however.

Comment: Thanks, after changing the working directory and setting shell execute to true it worked correctly.

Thanks again for the speedy response.

Answer (score 1):

So far there's only enough info to answer your final question.  Yes, you can include command line arguments as [shown here](http://dotnetperls.com/process-start-net).  Look at the section titled "=== Program that runs EXE (C#) ==="

Answer (score 1):

To add command line arguments:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\dan\\Desktop\\test.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // Put your arguments here
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

After the program has been compiled into an EXE, it shouldn't matter what language it was written in.

As for the program arguments, you need to take a look at the ProcessStartInfo class, and the override of Process.Start() that uses it: [Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in python, are you expecting verbose output?

In my case the output buffer got full and hence execution stalled.