# loading applications in .net

Tags: .net

how to laod an application in .net and how to get the memory usage  and cpu utilization of the loaded application.

Comment: By load, do you mean execute?

Comment: Ask only one question at a time.  Both are well covered by other threads at SO.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reference this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526481/execute-c-exe-from-c-form-using-process-start) for starting an application.  You can use the same [System.diagnostics.process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_properties.aspx) object to find the information you need as to memory access.  You can also the retrive the amount of time the processor has spent on this process.  If you want to retrieve the processor utilization you can use a performance counter.